# Extending Spine - Change storage type

Tags: spine.js

As part of a dissertation project I am looking to extend Spine.Model in order to support editing of realtime objects. 
My current spine application is using Model.local. When I run the app using dev tools of the browser, I can see all my models being stored in a map. What I want to do is have Spine use my own map (realtime map from google)  for storing Models, and then override functions like create, update, destroy to work with drive api.

After going through documentation (and while not having much experience with .coffee or .js) I could not figure out how I can make spine use my own map for storing models.

If someone can tell me how I can make it use my own map, or at least point me to the right direction that would be great.

p.s: If the implementation is successful with a clean solution, I will be hopefully be able to add this as contribution to the framework.

---

In case the solution above is not possible, what I will try to do is catch events on model create/update/destroy and copy them on my own map. For that solution, which methods from Model.ajax I need to modify?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, I would start by looking into overwritting the Model.attributes function

```
attributes: ->
  result = {}
  for key in @constructor.attributes when key of this
    if typeof @[key] is 'function'
      result[key] = @[key]()
    else
      result[key] = @[key]
  result.id = @id if @id
  result
```

that is what is used when sending models in and out of storage via Model.toJOSN

```
toJSON: ->
  @attributes()
```